# Scan dynamoDB table with restricted read or throughput limit

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Does anyone have a sample java code that does a scan operation on dynamoDB table where the scan operation uses only certain percentage of the throughput limit ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know elastic map reduce can do this.

Answer (score 5):

Yesterday we published a blog post on how to do [Rate Limited Scans in Amazon DynamoDB](http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx3VAYQIZ3Q0ZVW/Rate-Limited-Scans-in-Amazon-DynamoDB) on the [AWS Java Developer Blog](https://java.awsblog.com/).  I'm not sure what programming language you're using, but if you're using Java, this approach, which uses the GoogleGuava [RateLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) class, could work for you.  But Greg's earlier reply is also correct.  If you're using Amazon Elastic Map Reduce, the DynamoDB plugin supports a [configurable read and write throughput percent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMR_Hive_Optimizing.html) to limit itself to when scanning your table.  DynamoDB's [Amazon Redshift integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/RedshiftforDynamoDB.html) also has this setting.

Here is a snippet from the blog post that shows how to perform a paginated Scan that limits itself to consuming 25 read capacity units per second using RateLimiter and the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/):

```
// Initialize the rate limiter to allow 25 read capacity units / sec
RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(25.0);

// Track how much throughput we consume on each page
int permitsToConsume = 1;

// Initialize the pagination token
Map<String, AttributeValue> exclusiveStartKey = null;

do {
    // Let the rate limiter wait until our desired throughput "recharges"
    rateLimiter.acquire(permitsToConsume);

    // Do the scan
    ScanRequest scan = new ScanRequest()
        .withTableName("ProductCatalog")
        .withLimit(100)
        .withReturnConsumedCapacity(ReturnConsumedCapacity.TOTAL)
        .withExclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey);
    ScanResult result = dynamodb.scan(scan);
    exclusiveStartKey = result.getLastEvaluatedKey();

    // Account for the rest of the throughput we consumed,
    // now that we know how much that scan request cost
    double consumedCapacity = result.getConsumedCapacity().getCapacityUnits();
    permitsToConsume = (int)(consumedCapacity - 1.0);
    if(permitsToConsume <= 0) {
        permitsToConsume = 1;
    }

    // Process results here
    processYourResults(result);

} while (exclusiveStartKey  != null);
```

Comment: Why -1.0 in this line ?     permitsToConsume = (int)(consumedCapacity - 1.0);